# Compare and retrieve unmatched values in 5 excels

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, comparison

I wrote the following code to compare and retrieve unmatched values between two excels and put the sheetname in front of the value that was retrieved from the sheet it was retrieved.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df1 = pd.read_excel('pre post.xlsx', 'pre')
df2 = pd.read_excel('pre post.xlsx', 'post')
result = df2.merge(df1, indicator = True, how = 'outer').loc\[lambda v: v\['\_merge'\] != 'both'\]
result\['\_merge'\] = result\['\_merge'\].map({'left_only': 'pre', 'right_only': 'post'})
result.to_excel('final.xlsx')
```

Now, I want to do the same thing with 5 excel workbooks containing huge amount of IP Addresses. Please help! I'm stuck!! The code below is the code I was trying:

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl 
df1 = pd.read_excel('excel1.xlsx') 
df2 = pd.read_excel('excel2.xlsx') 
df3 = pd.read_excel('excel3.xlsx') 
df4 = pd.read_excel('excel4.xlsx') 
df5 = pd.read_excel('excel5.xlsx') 
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5] 
filenames = ['excel1.xlsx', 'excel2.xlsx', 'excel3.xlsx', 'excel4.xlsx', 'excel5.xlsx'] 
result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index = True, sort =False) 
unmatched_values = [] 
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):     
    unmatched = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)     
    for _, row in df.iterrows():         
        if row.tolist() not in result.values.tolist():             
            row['_filename'] = filenames[i]             
            unmatched = unmatched.append(row)     
    unmatched_values.append(unmatched) 
unmatched_df = pd.concat(unmatched_values, ignore_index = True)
unmatched_df.to_excel('unmatched_values.xlsx', index = False)
```

This code is not retrieving any values and is not working. Moreover, it is more complex than the above code.
What should I do?